# Efficient algorithm for expression parser (Java)

Tags: java, parsing, expression

I am trying to design an algorithm that can parse an expression in the form of a String. I want to be able to extract the operands and the operation from the given expression. Also, I want the algorithm to recognize bracket balance. No need for precedence of operations, as the input of the algorithm will include brackets if there are more than 1 binary operations. For unary operations, if a "-" appears before a bracket, it means the entire expression inside the respective brackets is the operand. Examples:

```
-parsing "a+b" gives "a" and "b" as operands and "+" as operation.
-parsing "(a/b) - (c*v)" gives "a/b" and "c*v" as operands and "-" as operation.
-parsing "((a/(b))) - (((c)*v))" gives the same result as above
-parsing "-a" gives operand as "a" and operation as "-"
-parsing "a + (-c/v)" gives "a" and "-c/v" as operands and "+" as operation
-parsing "-(c)" gives "c" is operand and "-" as operands
-parsing "(-(c))" gives same result as above
```

Thanks

Comment: Please, share your **attempt** and specify the problem you've encountered. Every question on StackOverflow is expected to demonstrate an effort. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: I do not understand why in `"(a/b) - (c*v)"`, the substrings `"a/b"` and `"c*v"` should be operands. They are expressions themselves.in prefix notation, it should evaluate to `- / a b * c v `. As AST, it should create a tree with three levels, with `-` being the root, having children `/` and `*`, `/` having children `a` and `b`  and `*` having children `c`and `v`.

Comment: The simplest expression parsing methods are probably "recursive descent" and "shunting yard."  Google for those and you'll find much info including SO articles. After you have a parser, adding actions code to emit the English you want won't be hard. This is another topic to look up: "syntax directed translation."

Comment: @Turing85 yes those are operands, and those operands each can also have operands and operations as in that example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
record Node(String name, Node left, Node right) {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Node[" + name
            + (left != null ? ", " + left : "")
            + (right != null ? ", " + right : "") + "]";
    }
}
```

and

```
static Node parse(String input) {
    return new Object() {
        int index = 0;

        int ch() { return index < input.length() ? input.charAt(index) : -1; }

        boolean eat(char expected) {
            while (Character.isWhitespace(ch())) ++index;
            if (ch() == expected) {
                ++index;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        Node factor() {
            Node node;
            boolean minus = eat('-');
            if (eat('(')) {
                node = expression();
                if (!eat(')'))
                    throw new RuntimeException("')' expected");
            } else if (Character.isAlphabetic(ch())) {
                node = new Node(Character.toString(ch()), null, null);
                ++index;
            } else
                throw new RuntimeException("unknown char '" + (char)ch() + "'");
            if (minus) node = new Node("-", node, null);
            return node;
        }

        Node expression() {
            Node node = factor();
            while (true)
                if (eat('*')) node = new Node("*", node, factor());
                else if (eat('/')) node = new Node("/", node, factor());
                else if (eat('+')) node = new Node("+", node, factor());
                else if (eat('-')) node = new Node("-", node, factor());
                else break;
            return node;
        }
    }.expression();
}
```

test:

```
static void testParse(String input) {
    System.out.printf("%-22s -> %s%n", input, parse(input));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    testParse("a+b");
    testParse("(a/b) - (c*v)");
    testParse("((a/(b))) - (((c)*v))");
    testParse("-a");
    testParse("-a + (-c/v)");
    testParse("-(c)");
    testParse("(-(c))");
}
```

output:

```
a+b                    -> Node[+, Node[a], Node[b]]
(a/b) - (c*v)          -> Node[-, Node[/, Node[a], Node[b]], Node[*, Node[c], Node[v]]]
((a/(b))) - (((c)*v))  -> Node[-, Node[/, Node[a], Node[b]], Node[*, Node[c], Node[v]]]
-a                     -> Node[-, Node[a]]
-a + (-c/v)            -> Node[+, Node[-, Node[a]], Node[/, Node[-, Node[c]], Node[v]]]
-(c)                   -> Node[-, Node[c]]
(-(c))                 -> Node[-, Node[c]]
```